# Error ‘access’ was not declared in this scope on compile c++

Tags: c++, g++

I've downloaded [this](https://github.com/opentibia/yatc) code on github but I'm having this error on `make` of the file `util.cpp`  line 212. It says

> error: ‘access’ was not declared in this scope
>
> int ret = access(tmppath, 0); //&s);

The part of the code is:

```
#ifndef WIN32
int yatc_makedirs(const char* path, int mode)
{
    char* tmppath = (char*)malloc(strlen(path)+1);
    for(const char* c = path; *c; c++)
    {
    if(*c=='/' && c-path > 0)
    {
        memcpy(tmppath,path,c-path);
        tmppath[c-path]=0;
        struct stat s;
        int ret = access(tmppath, 0); //&s);
        if(ret)
        {
            int mdret;
            if((mdret=mkdir(tmppath, mode)))
            {
                free(tmppath);
                return mdret;
            }
        }
    }
}
free(tmppath);
return 0;
}
#endif
```

The includes are:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#ifndef WIN32
#include <sys/stat.h> // mkdir
#include <errno.h>
#endif
#include "util.h"

#ifdef WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h> // needed for ShellExecute
#endif

#include "macutil.h"
#include "product.h"


#define WINCE_INSTALLDIR "/Storage Card/YATC/"
```

I didn't found documentation about this "access" function, am I missing some include here? The `g++` command (on linux terminal) was:

> g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.   -DDEBUGLEVEL_BUILDTIME=0  -DUSE_OPENGL -DDESTDIRS=\"/usr/local:/usr/local/share/:/usr/local/share/:/usr/local/share/yatc-data/:/usr/local/share/yatc-data/:/usr/local/share/tibia/:/usr/local/share/tibia/\"  -Wall -g -O2 -MT util.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/util.Tpo -c -o util.o util.cpp

Comment: [`access()` is provided from `<unistd.h>`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/access), which I see nowhere in your include lists.

Comment: On the off-chance you're trying this on Windows (it looks like the code could do so), [`access` is brought in with `io.h`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy.aspx). Good luck.